# Almost disjoint families on $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Suppose there is a family of $\aleph_3$ unbounded subsets of $\omega_1$ in which no set is contained in a countable union of other sets. Must there exist a (mod countable) almost disjoint family of unbounded subsets of $\omega_1$ of size $\aleph_3$?

Comment: According to a magic 8-ball website, all signs point to yes.

Comment: How about doing $Add(\omega_1, \omega_3)$ over a model of GCH. Seems to me that $\mathfrak{a}_{\omega_1}$ is $\aleph_2$ and the collection of Cohen subsets of $\omega_1$ satisfies your property

Comment: The sets of initial segments of the Cohen subsets form an almost disjoint family of size $\aleph_3$.

Comment: Oh right clearly I didn't read carefully and think the question is about $\mathfrak{a}_{\omega_1}$....